# SharePoint online backed api impersonating a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We have a web application (ASP.NET Core) (with attached WebAPI layer). Part of the application allows a user to create an email with an attachment. This works by within the website selecting a person in the system, typing a message and then selecting a document from a particular SharePoint Online folder. Some of the documents in the folder may have restricted permissions so not every user is allowed to see them or select them.

The web application is likely to use OpenID to log the user on (against Azure AD) and then issue a cookie. The WebAPI is currently custom token authenticated.

I there anyway the WebAPI layer can user get a token for the user to contact the SharePoint API.

Something like:

1. Connect to the GraphAPI and use just the username to retrieve an access token for the user
2. Connect to a SharePointAPI using the access token to retrieve a security trimmed list of documents

I can guess the answer is no and the words OAUTH token will be mentioned but just checking.

Comment: I think you are looking for Azure AD on-behalf-of-flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are trying to achieve is the propagation of delegated user identity and permission from one app to another. Here is how it can be achieved with ["on-behalf-of-flow".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
Here is a [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof) with asp.net. If this helps do mark the answer as accepted.